# Scala case classes with Mixin traits

Tags: scala

I am trying to use a trait as a mixin with a case class.

```
case class Team(name:String)

trait WinStreak{}
```

and I would like to use it like so:

```
val team = Team("name") with WinStreak
```

Apparently I cannot do this.  Is this because case classes use the companion object to create an instance of your class?  I know the other solution would be to just extend the trait in my class def, but I would like to know if its possible to create it mixin style.

Answer (score 26):

Because `Team("name")` is actually a method call to `Team.apply("name")`, which create the object inside the apply method.

Create the object using `new` keyword should do the trick:

```
case class Team(name:String)
trait WinStreak{}

val x = new Team("name") with WinStreak
```

Comment: Good Point.  I just realized that when using case classes you can't use a private constructor and disallow access to the constructor... Thanks for pointing that out.